# Python / XML closing tag error - unable to parse

Tags: python, html, xml, tags

the following code gives me the python error 'failed to parse' addon.xml:

(I've used an online checker and it says "error on line 33 at column 15: Opening and ending tag mismatch: description line 0 and extension" - which is the very end of the /extension end tag at the end of the document).

Any advice would be appreciated. This worked yesterday and I have no idea why it's not working at all

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<addon id="plugin.audio.criminalpodcast" name="Criminal Podcast" version="1.1.0" provider-name="leopheard">
<requires>
<import addon="xbmc.python" version="2.1.0"/>
<import addon="script.module.xbmcswift2" version="2.4.0"/>
<import addon="script.module.beautifulsoup4" version="4.3.1"/>
<import addon="script.module.requests" version="1.1.0"/>
<import addon="script.module.routing" version="0.2.0"/>   </requires>
```

```
<provides>audio</provides>  </extension>
<extension point="xbmc.addon.metadata">
    <platform>all</platform>
    <language></language>
    <summary lang="en"></summary>
    <description lang="en">description    </description>

    <license>The MIT License (MIT)</license>
<forum>https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=344790</forum>
<email>leopheard@gmail.com</email>
<source>https://github.com/leopheard/criminalpodcast</source>
<website>http://www.thisiscriminal.com</website>
    <audio_guide></audio_guide>
    <assets>
    <icon>icon.png</icon>
        <fanart>fanart.jpg</fanart>
        <screenshot>resources/media/Criminal_SocialShare_2.png</screenshot>
        <screenshot>resources/media/Criminal_SocialShare_3.png</screenshot>
        <screenshot>resources/media/Radiotopia-logo.png</screenshot>
            </assets>
```

Comment: Did you paste the whole file? I don't see a /extension tag at the end of the document.

Comment: Looks like `</extension>` moved one/few line/s up

Comment: You've got a closing `</extension>` tag _before_ the opening tag.  There is no closing `</addon>` tag nor `</requires>` tag.  This xml is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Your "XML" file is not well-formed, so it cannot be parsed. Find out how it was created, correct the process so the problem does not occur again, and then regenerate the file.

Files that are vaguely XML-like but not well-formed are pretty well useless. Repair is sometimes possible if the errors are very systematic, but that doesn't appear to the the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time a "failed to parse" error msg is due to the XML File itself.
Check you're XML File for the correct formatting.
I once forgot the root tag and had the same error message.